# Time coming in NSDate format

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

I'm using `ActionSheetDatePicker` for time picker i change mode in picker as `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` to take Hours and Minutes. It works well displayed Hours and min but when i getting Hrs and Min it return me `NSDate` init.
Ex. I selected 5 min to return me 300, so i get.
Here is code :

```
    ActionSheetDatePicker *datePicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select a time" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer selectedDate:self.selectedTime target:self action:@selector(ExtrTravelTimeWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];
    datePicker.minuteInterval = minuteInterval;
    [datePicker showActionSheetPicker];
```

and delegate

```
- (void)ExtrTravelTimeWasSelected:(NSDate *)selectedTime element:(id)element {
    self.selectedTime = selectedTime;
}
```

So Is there any way to convert 300(**NSDate**) to Hr and Min ?

Comment: Use NSDateComponents.

Comment: how i get that?

Comment: Could you please share log of selected time

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you're getting the value in seconds. try the following:

```
-(NSString *)getTimeStringFromSeconds:(double)seconds
{
  NSDateComponentsFormatter *dcFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
  dcFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
  dcFormatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
  dcFormatter.unitsStyle = 
  NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
 return [dcFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:seconds];
}
```

Comment: but im getting NSDate. How i pass double ?

Comment: After looking at their github and I saw this comment. //selectedDate is NSDate or NSNumber for "UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer" So in your case it's returning an NSNumber. You can use the double value on that

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have updated your code,

```
- (void)ExtrTravelTimeWasSelected:(NSDate *)selectedTime element:(id)element {
    self.selectedTime = selectedTime;
   // Split up the date components
   NSDateComponents *time = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                          components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute
                          fromDate:selectedTime];
   NSLog(@"h:mm::%zd:%2zd",[time hour],[time minute]);

}
```